# Cannot update label size and legend title automatically in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Recently, I built a small simple shiny website which just has a visualization function.

The aim is to visualize scatter data and adjust different parameters.

But I met a problem that the X and Y axises label size but also the legend title of the figure didn't update when I tried to use different parameters after the data uploaded.

The other parameters work well, such as point size, point shape and so on.

I referred to many methods but all of them doesn't work.

So here I need your help on my problem.

**1. Why the X and Y axises label size of the figure doesn't update when
I change them.**

**2. How to change the legend title.**

By the way, here I use [iris.xlsx](https://s2.smu.edu/tfomby/eco5385_eco6380/data/Iris.xls) as the sample data.

Thanks in advance !

Here is my Shiny script:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(pheatmap)
library(openxlsx)
library(viridis)
library(plotly)
library(DESeq2)
library(limma)
library(edgeR)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(statmod)
library(VennDiagram)
library(rsconnect)
#install.packages("colourpicker")
library(shinyWidgets)
library(colourpicker)
#install.packages("shinyjs")
library(shinyjs)
# install.packages("RColorBrewer")
library(RColorBrewer)
require(shinysky)
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("AnalytixWare/ShinySky")
#BiocManager::install("shinysky")
#install.packages("plotly")
# 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny grocery"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarMenuID",  
                #menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                menuItem("Basic data visualization", tabName = "data_visualization", icon = icon("image"),
                         
                         menuSubItem("Scatter plot", tabName = "scatter_plot", icon = icon("braille"))
                )
    )
  ),
  
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    
    useShinyjs(),  # 
    
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
        .shiny-notification {
          left: 20px !important;
          bottom: 20px !important;
          right: auto !important;
          top: auto !important;
          background-color: #E74C3C; 
          color: black; /* text color */
        }
        .custom-margin {
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      ")),
      tags$style(HTML("
      .custom-column-padding {
        padding-right: 5px !important;
        padding-left: 5px !important;
      }
    "))
    ),
      
      ######################################## # scatter_plot
      
      tabItem(tabName = "scatter_plot",
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 4,
                       #style = "background-color: black; padding: 20px;",
                       #style = "height: 200px;", # 
                       fluidRow(
                         box(title = "Settings", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                             collapsible = TRUE, 
                             width = 12,
                             fileInput("scatter_data", "Choose a data file", accept = c(".csv", ".txt", ".xlsx")),
                             actionButton("scatter_button", "Generate Scatter Plot"),
                             downloadButton("download_scatter", "Download Scatter Plot")
                         )
                       ),
                       fluidRow(
                         box(title = "Scatter Plot Parameters", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                             collapsible = TRUE, 
                             width = 12,
                             column(width = 4,
                                    selectInput("x_col", "X-axis Column", choices = NULL),
                                    selectInput("y_col", "Y-axis Column", choices = NULL),
                                    selectInput("group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = NULL),
                                    sliderInput("x_label_size", "X Label Size", min = 8, max = 24, value = 12),
                                    sliderInput("y_label_size", "Y Label Size", min = 8, max = 24, value = 12)
                             ),
                             column(width = 4,
                                    sliderInput("plot_width", "Plot Width", min = 100, max = 900, value = 800),
                                    sliderInput("plot_height", "Plot Height", min = 100, max = 750, value = 600),
                                    #jscolorInput("point_color", "Point Color", value = "#56B4E9"),
                                    colourpicker::colourInput("point_color", "Point Color", value = "#56B4E9"),
                                    selectInput("point_shape", "Point Shape", choices = 0:25, selected = 20),
                                    sliderInput("point_size", "Point Size", min = 1, max = 10, value = 2),
                                    sliderInput("point_alpha", "Point Alpha", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1, step = 0.1)
                                    
                             )
                             
                             
                             
                         )
                       )
                ),
                #plotOutput("scatter_plot_output")
                column(width = 8,
                       #plotOutput("scatter_plot_output",width = "100%", height = "500px")  # 
                       box(title = "Scatter Plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                           collapsible = TRUE, 
                           width = 12,
                           plotOutput("scatter_plot_output",width = "100%",height = "750px")  # 
                       )
                )
              )
      )
      
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  ###########################################   Basic data visualization 
  
  scatterPlotObj <- reactiveVal()
  data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  buttonClicked <- reactiveVal(FALSE)  
  
  observe({
    req(input$scatter_data)  # 
    df<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
    data(df)
    # 
    col_names <- colnames(data())
    
    # 
    updateSelectInput(session, "x_col", "X-axis Column", choices = col_names)
    updateSelectInput(session, "y_col", "Y-axis Column", choices = col_names)
    # 
    group_cols <- col_names[sapply(data(), function(col) is.factor(col) || is.character(col))]
    
    # 如果存在分组信息，则添加到选择器，否则添加"None"
    if(length(group_cols) > 0) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = c(group_cols,"None"))
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = "None", selected = "None")
    }
    
  })
  
  # 
  ###########
  observeEvent(input$scatter_button, {
    df <- data()  # 
    req(df, input$x_col, input$y_col)
    #data<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
    
    #req(input$scatter_data, input$x_col, input$y_col)
    
    # 
    if(input$group_col != "None" && !is.null(df[[input$group_col]])) {
      unique_groups <- length(unique(df[[input$group_col]]))
      color_values <- brewer.pal(min(unique_groups, 12), "Set3")
      scatterPlotObj(ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,input$x_col], y = df[,input$y_col],color = df[,input$group_col])) +
                       geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                  size = input$point_size, 
                                  alpha = input$point_alpha
                                  #color = data[,input$group_col]
                       ) +
                       #facet_wrap(~ data[,input$group_col]) 
                       scale_color_manual(values = color_values) +
                       #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
                       labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$label_size),
                             axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$label_size))+
                       theme_classic())
    } else {
      # "None"
      scatterPlotObj(ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,input$x_col], y = df[,input$y_col],color = input$point_color)) +
                       geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                  size = input$point_size,
                                  
                                  alpha = input$point_alpha) +
                       #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col,color="Type") +
                       labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$label_size),
                             axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$label_size))+
                       theme_classic())
    }
    buttonClicked(TRUE)  # 
  })
  
  
  
  output$scatter_plot_output <- renderPlot({
    # 
    scatterPlotObj()
  }, width = function() { 
    #paste(input$plot_width, "px", sep = "")
    input$plot_width
  }, height = function() { 
    input$plot_height
    #paste(input$plot_height, "px", sep = "")
  })
  
  # 
  observe({
    #data<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
    req(data(),
        input$x_col, input$y_col, input$group_col,input$x_label_size,input$y_label_size,
        input$plot_width,input$plot_height, input$point_color,
        input$point_shape,input$point_size,input$point_alpha,input$point_stroke)
    #df <- data()
    # 
    if(buttonClicked()) {
      if(input$group_col != "None" && !is.null( data()[[input$group_col]])) {
        unique_groups <- length(unique( data()[[input$group_col]]))
        color_values <- brewer.pal(min(unique_groups, 12), "Set3")
        scatterPlotObj(ggplot( data(), aes(x =  data()[,input$x_col], y =  data()[,input$y_col],color =  data()[,input$group_col])) +
                         geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                    size = input$point_size, 
                                    alpha = input$point_alpha
                                    #color = data[,input$group_col]
                         ) +
                         #facet_wrap(~ data[,input$group_col]) 
                         scale_color_manual(values = color_values) +
                         #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
                         #guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Type'))+
                         labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                         theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$label_size),
                               axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$label_size))+
                         theme_classic())
      } else {
        # "None"
        scatterPlotObj(ggplot(data(), aes(x = data()[,input$x_col], y = data()[,input$y_col],color = data()[,input$group_col])) +
                         geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                    size = input$point_size,
                                    
                                    alpha = input$point_alpha) +
                         #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
                         #guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Type'))+
                         labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                         theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$label_size),
                               axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$label_size))+
                         theme_classic())
      }
    }
    #print(paste("X label size:", input$x_label_size))
    #print(paste("Y label size:", input$y_label_size))
  })
 
}

# 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the label size, you can call `theme_classic()` before changing the label size. Next, legend title can be change with `name` in `scale_color_manual`.  Please consider posting a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the future.  There is no need to include all the libraries you mentioned to show your error.  Try this

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Shiny grocery"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarMenuID",  
                #menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                menuItem("Basic data visualization", tabName = "data_visualization", icon = icon("image"),
                         
                         menuSubItem("Scatter plot", tabName = "scatter_plot", icon = icon("braille"))
                )
    )
  ),
  
  
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),  # 
    
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
        .shiny-notification {
          left: 20px !important;
          bottom: 20px !important;
          right: auto !important;
          top: auto !important;
          background-color: #E74C3C; 
          color: black; /* text color */
        }
        .custom-margin {
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      ")),
      tags$style(HTML("
      .custom-column-padding {
        padding-right: 5px !important;
        padding-left: 5px !important;
      }
    "))
    ),
    
    ######################################## # scatter_plot
    
    tabItem(tabName = "scatter_plot",
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 4,
                     #style = "background-color: black; padding: 20px;",
                     #style = "height: 200px;", # 
                     fluidRow(
                       box(title = "Settings", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                           collapsible = TRUE, 
                           width = 12,
                           # fileInput("scatter_data", "Choose a data file", accept = c(".csv", ".txt", ".xlsx")),
                           actionButton("scatter_button", "Generate Scatter Plot"),
                           downloadButton("download_scatter", "Download Scatter Plot")
                       )
                     ),
                     fluidRow(
                       box(title = "Scatter Plot Parameters", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                           collapsible = TRUE, 
                           width = 12,
                           column(width = 4,
                                  selectInput("x_col", "X-axis Column", choices = NULL),
                                  selectInput("y_col", "Y-axis Column", choices = NULL),
                                  selectInput("group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = NULL),
                                  sliderInput("x_label_size", "X Label Size", min = 8, max = 24, value = 12),
                                  sliderInput("y_label_size", "Y Label Size", min = 8, max = 24, value = 12)
                           ),
                           column(width = 4,
                                  sliderInput("plot_width", "Plot Width", min = 100, max = 900, value = 800),
                                  sliderInput("plot_height", "Plot Height", min = 100, max = 750, value = 600),
                                  #jscolorInput("point_color", "Point Color", value = "#56B4E9"),
                                  colourpicker::colourInput("point_color", "Point Color", value = "#56B4E9"),
                                  selectInput("point_shape", "Point Shape", choices = 0:25, selected = 20),
                                  sliderInput("point_size", "Point Size", min = 1, max = 10, value = 2),
                                  sliderInput("point_alpha", "Point Alpha", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1, step = 0.1)
                                  
                           )
                       )
                     )
              ),
              #plotOutput("scatter_plot_output")
              column(width = 8,
                     #plotOutput("scatter_plot_output",width = "100%", height = "500px")  # 
                     box(title = "Scatter Plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                         collapsible = TRUE, 
                         width = 12,
                         plotOutput("scatter_plot_output",width = "100%",height = "750px")  # 
                     )
              )
            )
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ###########################################   Basic data visualization 
  
  scatterPlotObj <- reactiveVal()
  data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  buttonClicked <- reactiveVal(FALSE)  
  
  observe({
    # req(input$scatter_data)  # 
    # df<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
    df <- mtcars
    data(df)
    # 
    col_names <- colnames(data())
    
    # 
    updateSelectInput(session, "x_col", "X-axis Column", choices = col_names[2:length(colnames)])
    updateSelectInput(session, "y_col", "Y-axis Column", choices = col_names[1])
    # 
    group_cols <- col_names[sapply(data(), function(col) is.factor(col) || is.character(col))]
    
    # 如果存在分组信息，则添加到选择器，否则添加"None"
    if(length(group_cols) > 0) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = c(group_cols,"None"))
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session, "group_col", "Grouping Column", choices = "None", selected = "None")
    }
    
  })
  
  # 
  ###########
  observeEvent(input$scatter_button, {
    df <- data()  # 
    req(df, input$x_col, input$y_col)
    #data<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
    
    #req(input$scatter_data, input$x_col, input$y_col)
    
    # 
    if(input$group_col != "None" && !is.null(df[[input$group_col]])) {
      unique_groups <- length(unique(df[[input$group_col]]))
      color_values <- brewer.pal(min(unique_groups, 12), "Set3")
      scatterPlotObj(ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,input$x_col], y = df[,input$y_col],color = df[,input$group_col])) +
                       geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                  size = input$point_size, 
                                  alpha = input$point_alpha
                                  #color = data[,input$group_col]
                       ) +
                       #facet_wrap(~ data[,input$group_col]) 
                       scale_color_manual(values = color_values, name = "My Name") +
                       #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
                       labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                       theme_classic() + 
                       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$x_label_size),
                             axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$y_label_size)) 
                       )
    } else {
      # "None"
      scatterPlotObj(ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,input$x_col], y = df[,input$y_col],color = input$point_color)) +
                       geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
                                  size = input$point_size, 
                                  alpha = input$point_alpha) +
                       #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col,color="Type") +
                       scale_color_manual(values = input$point_color, name = "My name") +                           ### <-----------
                       labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
                       theme_classic() +                                                          ###  choose theme and then change label size
                       theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$x_label_size),              ### <-------
                             axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$y_label_size))              ### <------- 
      )
    }
    buttonClicked(TRUE)  # 
  })
  
  
  
  output$scatter_plot_output <- renderPlot({
    # 
    scatterPlotObj()
  }, width = function() { 
    #paste(input$plot_width, "px", sep = "")
    input$plot_width
  }, height = function() { 
    input$plot_height
    #paste(input$plot_height, "px", sep = "")
  })
  
  
  # 
  # observe({
  #   #data<-read.xlsx(input$scatter_data$datapath)
  #   # req(data(),
  #   #     input$x_col, input$y_col, input$group_col,input$x_label_size,input$y_label_size,
  #   #     input$plot_width,input$plot_height, input$point_color,
  #   #     input$point_shape,input$point_size,input$point_alpha,input$point_stroke)
  #   #df <- data()
  #   # 
  #   if(buttonClicked()) {
  #     if(input$group_col != "None" && !is.null( data()[[input$group_col]])) {
  #       unique_groups <- length(unique( data()[[input$group_col]]))
  #       color_values <- brewer.pal(min(unique_groups, 12), "Set3")
  #       scatterPlotObj(ggplot(data(), aes(x = .data[[input$x_col]], y = .data[[input$y_col]],color = .data[[input$group_col]])) +
  #       # scatterPlotObj(ggplot( data(), aes(x =  data()[,input$x_col], y =  data()[,input$y_col],color =  data()[,input$group_col])) +
  #                        geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
  #                                   size = input$point_size, 
  #                                   alpha = input$point_alpha
  #                                   #color = data[,input$group_col]
  #                        ) +
  #                        #facet_wrap(~ data[,input$group_col]) 
  #                        scale_color_manual(values = color_values) +
  #                        #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
  #                        #guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Type'))+
  #                        labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
  #                        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$x_label_size),
  #                              axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$y_label_size))+
  #                        theme_classic())
  #     } else {
  #       # "None"
  #       scatterPlotObj(ggplot(data(), aes(x = .data[[input$x_col]], y = .data[[input$y_col]],color = input$point_color)) +
  #                        geom_point(shape = as.numeric(input$point_shape), 
  #                                   size = input$point_size,
  #                                   alpha = input$point_alpha) +
  #                        scale_color_manual(values = input$point_color) + 
  #                        #labs(x = input$x_col, y = input$y_col) +
  #                        #guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Type'))+
  #                        labs(x = "Weight", y = "Miles/(US) gallon") +
  #                        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = input$x_label_size),
  #                              axis.title.y = element_text(size = input$y_label_size))+
  #                        theme_classic())
  #     }
  #   }
  #   print(paste("X label size:", input$x_label_size))
  #   #print(paste("Y label size:", input$y_label_size))
  # })
  
}

# 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Maybe you don't remember that you help me a lot on my shiny questions.